# AWS eclipse plugin - installation error

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an error from Eclipse, after installing the aws plugin and restarting Eclipse. I'm currently using Kepler Java EE edition. I even tried with Luna, and every time when I download the Eclipse plugin from aws website and restart Eclipse after installation (which is mandated by the install process), this error pops up.

[image: AWS eclipse plugin error]